# How does one determine chirality experimentally?

Tags: particle-physics, chirality

The Standard Model says that only left-handed electrons participate in weak interaction. A very natural question for novices like me is then: How can we tell, experimentally, if an electron is left-handed or right-handed? I understand that chirality is an intrinsic quantum number of the particle field that is different from the helicity for massive particles.

Comment: Not exactly the same, but related:  http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13688/left-and-right-handed-fermions

Comment: Duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/161170/how-can-we-measure-chirality-in-experiments/161522#161522